# Plotly Express Scatter Mapbox is missing categories when setting animation_frame

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, mapbox, plotly-express

So I'm trying to get a plot with px.scatter_mapbox where the animation_frame is set to brand_name. In every frame, I then want to see on the map the different purchasing_models (different colors). The problem now is that whenever I set the animation_frame to brand_name, only one purchase_model per frame is displayed in the plot. If I don't set the animation_frame, I can see all the purchase_models (but as there are many, I need the frames to structure it).

To achieve this, I did the following:

```
data = {'brand_name': ['BMW', 'BMW', 'BMW', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes'],
        'purchasing_model_y': ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'C-Class', 'E-Class', 'S-Class'],
        'lat': [52.5200, 52.5200, 52.5200, 48.1351, 48.1351, 48.1351],
        'long': [13.4050, 13.4050, 13.4050, 11.5820, 11.5820, 11.5820],
        'count_customers': [10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 35]}

full_df4 = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(full_df4, lat="lat", lon="long", color='purchasing_model_y', size='count_customers',
                    animation_frame='brand_name',
                    zoom=zoom, center=center,
                   size_max=40, hover_name='community_name', 
                  height = 600, width = 1000, title='Allocation of Customers by Car Brand and Model ', mapbox_style="open-street-map")


fig.update_layout(font_size=16,title_font_size = 24, mapbox_accesstoken=api_token)
```

with

zoom, center being calculated with the following function:

```
def zoom_center(lons: tuple=None, lats: tuple=None, lonlats: tuple=None,
        format: str='lonlat', projection: str='mercator',
        width_to_height: float=2.0) -> (float, dict):
    """Finds optimal zoom and centering for a plotly mapbox.
    Must be passed (lons & lats) or lonlats.
    Temporary solution awaiting official implementation, see:
    https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/3434
    
    Parameters
    --------
    lons: tuple, optional, longitude component of each location
    lats: tuple, optional, latitude component of each location
    lonlats: tuple, optional, gps locations
    format: str, specifying the order of longitud and latitude dimensions,
        expected values: 'lonlat' or 'latlon', only used if passed lonlats
    projection: str, only accepting 'mercator' at the moment,
        raises `NotImplementedError` if other is passed
    width_to_height: float, expected ratio of final graph's with to height,
        used to select the constrained axis.
    
    Returns
    --------
    zoom: float, from 1 to 20
    center: dict, gps position with 'lon' and 'lat' keys

    >>> print(zoom_center((-109.031387, -103.385460),
    ...     (25.587101, 31.784620)))
    (5.75, {'lon': -106.208423, 'lat': 28.685861})
    """
    if lons is None and lats is None:
        if isinstance(lonlats, tuple):
            lons, lats = zip(*lonlats)
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                'Must pass lons & lats or lonlats'
            )
    
    maxlon, minlon = max(lons), min(lons)
    maxlat, minlat = max(lats), min(lats)
    center = {
        'lon': round((maxlon + minlon) / 2, 6),
        'lat': round((maxlat + minlat) / 2, 6)
    }
    
    # longitudinal range by zoom level (20 to 1)
    # in degrees, if centered at equator
    lon_zoom_range = np.array([
        0.0007, 0.0014, 0.003, 0.006, 0.012, 0.024, 0.048, 0.096,
        0.192, 0.3712, 0.768, 1.536, 3.072, 6.144, 11.8784, 23.7568,
        47.5136, 98.304, 190.0544, 360.0
    ])
    
    if projection == 'mercator':
        margin = 1.2
        height = (maxlat - minlat) * margin * width_to_height
        width = (maxlon - minlon) * margin
        lon_zoom = np.interp(width , lon_zoom_range, range(20, 0, -1))
        lat_zoom = np.interp(height, lon_zoom_range, range(20, 0, -1))
        zoom = round(min(lon_zoom, lat_zoom), 2)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            f'{projection} projection is not implemented'
        )
    
    return zoom, center
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your intention to optimize the zoom and center of the map, but to see the animation with the brand at the same time, you would need to add different display order data. For example. Add the number of occurrences of the brand name and use that number as the frame value for the animation. `full_df4['display_no'] = full_df4['brand_name'].groupby((full_df4['brand_name'] != full_df4['brand_name'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1; ...fig = px.scatter_mapbox(...,animation_frame='display_no',...)`